# Font is coming totally different in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, fonts

Hi I am using a font and I have generated a webfont kit. But on firefox and Chrome the font is coming out totally differently They even do not resmble at all. I have also attached some images about how the font looks like. Any suggestions on how to do it? Any solution would be greatly appreciated thanks in advance. I am using "petescriptregular" font.

This is how I am Using the fonts in my CSS file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyriadPro-Regular';
  src: url('/www/magenta/wp-content/themes/ecorecycle/fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  url('/www/magenta/wp-content/themes/ecorecycle/fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('/www/magenta/wp-content/themes/ecorecycle/fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype'), url('/www/magenta/wp-content/themes/ecorecycle/fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.svg#MyriadPro-Regular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'petescriptregular';
   src: url('/www/magenta/wp-content/themes/ecorecycle/fonts/petescript-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/www/magenta/wp-content/themes/ecorecycle/fonts/petescript-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/www/magenta/wp-content/themes/ecorecycle/fonts/petescript-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('/www/magenta/wp-content/themes/ecorecycle/fonts/petescript-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/www/magenta/wp-content/themes/ecorecycle/fonts/petescript-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/www/magenta/wp-content/themes/ecorecycle/fonts/petescript-webfont.svg#petescriptregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Firefox Image:
[image: Firefox Image]

Chrome Image:
[image: Chrome Image]

Comment: This is "petescriptregular" font.

Comment: If you have generated a webfont kit have you used all the relevant prefixes and special cases for each property?

Comment: These are two different fonts. Maybe you created a  mixed font file, or made an error in your CSS, or use the wrong URL for a web font, or a dozen other possible errors. We wouldn't know because you haven't posted any code.

Comment: I am posting code now

Comment: i just checked on both Chrome as well as Firefox and found them to be same. I checked using this http://www.linotype.com/487626/PetescriptRegular-product.html and entering sample text

Comment: As @HoboSapiens said, probably you have missed some small detail

Comment: The lower font is PeteScript. The upper font is something else. I have already speculated as to why.

Comment: Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the .otf format of your font for firefox and .otf for IE
you could convert the font format like this site 
https://everythingfonts.com